# Writing a prompt inside a while-loop

Tags: javascript, while-loop, do-while, prompt

I want the code to continue, only if the user inputs rock, paper or scissors, but it seems to continue after I re-enter any input the second time, despite it passing the condition in the while loop. For example, if I type "asdf" it will ask me to re-enter the input, but then if I do "asdf" again, it exits the while-loop and logs out "asdf". I want it to keep prompting the user until they enter "rock", "paper" or "scissors"

```
var userChoice = prompt("Enter rock, paper, or scissors", "rock").toLowerCase();


while (userChoice !== "rock" && userChoice !== "paper" && userChoice !== "scissors" ) {
  userChoice = prompt("renter Please");
}

console.log(userChoice);
```

Comment: Seems to work as you want. Copy/pasted here: https://jsfiddle.net/nkma2816/

Comment: weird. You're right, but it doesn't work on jsbin

Comment: So then why didn't you link there in your question?

Comment: Because I wasn't aware that jsbin was the issue. Shoulda linked it anyway though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if the user reenters more than one time you return false or exit the system.

```js
     var userChoice = prompt("Enter rock, paper, or scissors").toLowerCase();
        while (userChoice != "rock" && userChoice != "paper" && userChoice !=
            "scissors") {
            userChoice = prompt("renter Please");
           
        }
        console.log(userChoice)
```

Comment: He says, 'I want it to keep prompting the user until they enter "rock", "paper" or "scissors"' ...so why are you breaking out of the loop?

Comment: @Jack Edited it with snippet. The problem he had was with his assignments

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you assign userChoice to a value of "paper" "scissors" or "rock" its value will stay that way if not changed so the while loop wont restart.

Try after you run whatever code comes after the while loop adding something like this.

```
while (userChoice !== "rock" && userChoice !== "paper" && userChoice !== "scissors" ) {
  userChoice = prompt("renter Please");
}

console.log(userChoice);

userChoice = 0;
```

This will only work however if your code is nested in another loop

```
loop{
    var userChoice = prompt("Enter rock, paper, or scissors", "rock").toLowerCase();

    var userChoice = prompt("Enter rock, paper, or scissors", "rock").toLowerCase();


    while (userChoice !== "rock" && userChoice !== "paper" && userChoice !== "scissors" ) {
      userChoice = prompt("renter Please");
    }

    console.log(userChoice);
    userChoice = 0;
}
```